# In-App browser increases memory consumption in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my app, user can visit link. I use in-app browser for that. But when user visits the site, memory consumption is increased from 25MB to 50MB and does not decrease even user closes the browser or come back to previous screen.

Here is the simple code I am using to open browser:

```
    AppMainBrowserViewController *mainBrowser = [[AppMainBrowserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppMainBrowserViewController" bundle:nil];
    mainBrowser.urlString = urlString;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainBrowser animated:YES];
```

In my `AppMainBrowserViewController`:

```
if ([InternetDetector isNetAvailable]) {

    if (self.processingIndicatorAlertView == Nil) {
        [self showIndicatorView];
    }

    //Request
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]];
    [self.mainWebView loadRequest:request];
} else {

    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE_MSG message:INTERNET_NOT_FOUND_MSG delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
```

Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is due to the cache of `NSURLCache`. Try that before launching the in-app browser it just set the cache to 0:

```
 int cacheSizeMemory = 0; 
    int cacheSizeDisk = 0; 
    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Comment: Still same memory is consumed.